# Python (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Add: 'undefined' and 'str')

Tags: python, string, undefined, typeerror

I'm new into python. Please, tell me what mistake I made.

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
print "elements:"
for a in list:
    print(a)
num=int(input("pick 1 element"))
print num + " is " + list.index(num)
```

Output:

```
elements:
1
2
3
4
pick 1 element
2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Add: 'undefined' and 'str'
```

If I make `num=str` it's `ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list`

Comment: print "%s is %s" % (num, list.index(num))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
print str(num) + " is " + str(list.index(num))
```

Your problem is that you need `num` to be a string when outputting it, but need it to be an `int` when indexing into the list. Even simpler, you could harness the power of Python's `print` function to do the conversions for you:

```
print num, "is", list.index(num)
```

Also, please don't name your lists `list`, which is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: `str(list.index(num))` as well?